# Tooltip arrow with same color as content background

Tags: html, css

so given this html/css

http://cdpn.io/gwkfy

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #369;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.tooltip:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 100%;
    top: calc(50% - 10px);
    width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

is it possible to have the arrow inherit the background color of the tooltip content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to have the arrow inherit the background color of the
>   tooltip content?

Well, no unless you use JavaScript.

However, you could set `border-color` property for the parent, and use `inherit` value for the child:

```css
.tooltip {
    background-color: #369;
    border-color: #369;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VX22K/)**

Comment: geez, awesome! why didn't i think of that simple solution! thanks a bunch.